# Add GestureRecognizer to row in gridview

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a grid where there are 3 columns containing 2 buttons and 1 label. What I want is to add a Tap gesture to each rows in the grid. I want the click event to be fired when the user taps anywhere in the grid row. Is there any way to do this?

I want to keep my layout as simple as possible. Before I was creating the same grid using multiple stacklayouts and adding gestures to the parent stacklayout. But for performance I want to do this using a grid view.

Comment: I just realised that `ContentView.GestureRecognizers` is not just applicable for `ContentView` but is also applicable to other UIElements like `Label` i.e., `<Label.GestureRecognizers ...>` works!. @hvaughan3 thanks, took idea from your answer.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I would suggest adding a `ContentView` (which is not as intensive as a `StackLayout`). Make it cover the whole row and add the `GestureRecognizer` to that, like so:

```
<ContentView HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
             VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
             Grid.Row="0"
             Grid.Column="0"
             Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
    <ContentView.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnTapped"/>
    </ContentView.GestureRecognizers>
</ContentView>
```

Comment: Then I will need 3 contentviews as I have 3 columns per rows and then adding gestures to all of them. That will be too long.

Comment: @AkashAmin Well you could create a single `ContentView` in your code behind or where ever and add it into your XAML 3 times so that only 1 needs to be created. Then if all of the `GestureRecognizer`s are the exact same, you could also attach the `GestureRecognizer` to the single `ContentView` instance and add the single instance to three different rows. Either way, you are going to have to add something to all three rows as you cannot attach a `GestureRecognizer` to a row by itself.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have solved this by putting the content view in the grid row and spanning across my columns.

Comment: @AkashAmin Glad it helped!

Comment: Could simply use a `BoxView`.